# What is the meaning of request time out from 13 to 30

Tags: time, request, out

tracert ncusar.org

```
Tracing route to ncusar.org [208.55.217.149]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.1
  2    47 ms    28 ms    35 ms  c-76-111-68-1.hsd1.va.comcast.net [76.111.68.1]
  3     9 ms    12 ms    11 ms  xe-4-0-0-32767-sur01.arlington.va.bad.comcast.net [68.85.139.33]
  4    26 ms    18 ms     9 ms  ae-22-0-ar04.capitolhghts.md.bad.comcast.net [68.85.114.33]
  5    13 ms    15 ms    12 ms  he-5-2-0-0-11-cr01.ashburn.va.ibone.comcast.net[68.86.90.245]
  6    13 ms    15 ms    15 ms  pos-0-3-0-0-pe01.ashburn.va.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.86.142]
  7    42 ms    27 ms    41 ms  66.208.233.42
  8    66 ms    27 ms    27 ms  216.6.87.158
  9    26 ms    27 ms    26 ms  ae-6.r00.stngva01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.2.61]
 10    27 ms    28 ms    26 ms  ae-0.r00.stngva01.us.wh.verio.net [129.250.27.187]
 11    29 ms    27 ms    26 ms  ge-25.a0801.stngva01.us.wh.verio.net [204.2.122.242]
 12    49 ms    35 ms    35 ms  va1-lav00016.vwh.net [209.238.145.5]
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the address refused responding to the ping on hop 13, and retried until the hop limit was reached. The host might have disabled ping responses on its server, or it may be simply offline.